# Из UTF в binaryString и обратно в java

Tags: java, кодировка, utf-8, binary, utf

Подскажите как правильно производить данную операцию.
Пробовал следующим образом, при сравнении выводит false(на любых символах).

```
    char a = 'q';
    String curBin = Long.toBinaryString(a);
    while (curBin.length() < 16) {
        curBin = "0" + curBin;
    }

    long charCode = Long.parseLong(curBin.substring(0, 16));
    String c = new Character((char)charCode).toString();
    String aStr = "" + a;

    System.out.println(c.equals(aStr));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы парсите из десятичной системы, а не из двоичной.
По умолчанию показатель = 10, но его можно задать явно.

```
long charCode = Long.parseLong(curBin.substring(0, 16), 2);
```

Comment: Точно, у лонга тоже ж есть redix в парсере

Comment: Как же все просто.. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
char a = 'q';
String curBin = Long.toBinaryString(a);
while (curBin.length() < 16) {
    curBin = "0" + curBin;
}

long charCode = new BigInteger(curBin.substring(0, 16), 2).longValue();

String c = Character.toString((char) charCode);
String aStr = "" + a;

System.out.println(c.equals(aStr));
```

`String aStr = "" + a;` тоже там не очень нужен - лучше сравнивать сразу с исходным символом:

```
System.out.println(c.equals(String.valueOf('q')));
```